# ¿Cómo extraer texto entre dos líneas?

Tags: python

Tengo un archivo de texto como se muestra en las fotos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que quiero hacer es que me tome solo el texto que hay en medio de:

```
"78897 TFFR Le Raizet, Guadeloupe Observations at 00Z 01 Apr 1973"
```

y

```
"78897 TFFR Le Raizet, Guadeloupe Observations at 012Z 01 Apr 1973"
```

Usé esto:

```
with open("archivo1.txt") as f:
   content = f.read()
   split_1 = content.split("78897 TFFR Le Raizet, Guadeloupe Observations at 00Z 01 Apr 1973")
text = ' '.join(' '.join(split_1).strip().split("78897 TFFR Le Raizet, Guadeloupe Observations at 12Z 01 Apr 1973"))
final_file = open("archivo2.txt", "w")
final_file.write(text)
final_file.close()
```

Pero esto lo que hace es que quita las líneas que le estoy indicando y no me da el resultado que quiero, que es el texto en medio de esas dos líneas alguien sabe cómo se puede hacer?

[Adjunto el archivo de texto](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1tGEG22EW1wHkD1zMoC9X13DFNQXzC8S5)

Comment: ¿Podrías publicar un enlace al documento de texto para probarlo? Con la imagen poco podemos hacer.

Comment: Acá lo tengo
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1tGEG22EW1wHkD1zMoC9X13DFNQXzC8S5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tienes que tener en cuenta que split te devuelve una lista.

Si haces `split("inicio")[1]` obtendrás todo el texto que aparece después de "inicio". Si a eso le haces un `split("fin")[0]` obtendrás todo el texto que aparece antes de "fin". Por lo tanto, obtienes el texto que aperece entre "inicio" y "fin". Le puedes añadir strip() para eliminar líneas vacías.

Supongamos un ejemplo más sencillo en el que tenemos este texto:

```
foo
foo
Hello World
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
Bye World
foo
foo
```

Con este código obtenemos el texto que aparece entre "Hello World" y "Bye World":

```
txtStart = "Hello World"
txtEnd = "Bye World"

f = open("archivo1.txt")
content = f.read()
text = content.split(txtStart)[1].split(txtEnd)[0].strip()

final_file = open("archivo2.txt", "w")
final_file.write(text)
final_file.close()
```

El archivo contendría:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

Ten en cuenta que si el texto inicial y final aparece varias veces, obtendrás sólo las lineas entre la primera vez que aparecen ambos. Entiendo que en tu caso es suficiente así.

Comment: Gracias, me sirvió mucho.

Answer (score 1):

puedes intentar con este codigo!

```
from pprint import pprint

start = "Hello World"
stop = "Bye World"

# inicializamos varibles y colocamos todos los textos a mayusculas
a= list()
start=start.upper()
stop=stop.upper()

#abrimos el archivo
with open('ts.txt','r') as f:
    content = f.readlines()
    # sp sera nuesta variable para start point
    sp = False

    # recorremos las lineas
    for i in content:
        #eliminamos los saltos de linea
        i=i.replace("\n","")
        # validamos si el texto en el recorrido es igual al de start 
        if start in i.upper():
            # agregamos el texto al arreglo
            a.append(i)
            # marcamos un inicio
            sp = True
            # saltamos a la siguiente interacion
            continue
        # validamos si el texto es igual a stop 
        if stop in i.upper():
            # si es igual a stop marcamos el final
            sp = False
        # si se marco un inicio agregamos valores al arreglo
        if sp:
            #creamos un nuevo arreglo en base a los espacios
            t = i.split(" ")
            # recorremos el nuevo arreglo
            for j in t:
                # agregamos los valores
                a.append(j)
    f.close()

# utilizamos pprint para que se pinte en pantalla de forma legible
pprint(a)
```